# How to express the skill when someone does not stop working until the task is done?

Tags: expressions

What is the skill of trying the best to finish a hard task assigned? 
While having impediments on the way, without complaining, exploring solutions and putting in practice till the end.

Comment: That's perseverance.

Comment: There are multiple multiple options: perseverance, persistence, tenacity, determination. Perseverance is the best suited though.

Comment: I don't see it as a skill, I see it as a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want *assiduous*.  The OED says:

> Of persons or agents: Constant in application to the business in hand, persevering, sedulous, unwearyingly diligent.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I hear such people referred to as having great *focus*.

Another term you hear a lot is *dogged* (typically pronounced almost like it is two words: dog ed). The word *dog* is sometimes used in English as a verb to describe the act of persistently chasing after someone or something. Dogged can be used as an adjective, and occasionally *doggedly* as an adverb.

In a more ambivalent sense, sometimes we use the metaphor or simile of a bulldog ("He's a bulldog"). This is an animal that is somewhat famous for refusing to let go of something it has bitten down on, even when you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

***Stick-to-itiveness*** is a fun word that fits well here and is surprisingly old--at least I would have assumed it was coined more recently.  It dates as far back as 1859.

> N. Amer. colloq. (OED)   The ability to stick to something; the
>   capacity to see a course of action through to the end; dogged
>   perseverance

Earliest usage according to OED was 1859 in the Detroit Free Press:

> "The rider, who had kept his seat with a commendable
>   stick-to-ativeness, was floored by the last feat and hurt by the
>   fall."

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stick-to-itiveness)